# grep a pattern that doesn't have dot after it

Tags: grep

File `a` contains,

```
abcd
abcd. defgh
defghabcd.
defgh. abcd
abcd .defgh
```

How can i print all the lines that has the pattern `abcd` without a dot suffix?

It must print,

```
abcd
defgh. abcd
abcd .defgh #. after any other character is good to go
```

I tried `grep 'abcd^[\.]' a`, it doesn't work.

Comment: while the regex from @cuongim is the more elegant solution, a series of `grep` would work, too. `grep -v 'abcd\.' file | grep 'abcd'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `^` outside of brackets `[...]` meaning beginning of line. And you will make mistakes when escaped dot inside brackets, `[^\.]` means anything except backslash `\` and dot `.`, not only dot `.`

Another note that `abcd[^.]` won't match *abcd* at the end of line.

So you need:

```
$ grep -E 'abcd([^.]|$)' <file
abcd
defgh. abcd
abcd .defgh
```

Comment: We posted about the same time, but I missed the extra `\\`, so I've just deleted my answer (+1).

Comment: @Costas: Ah, my bad. Removed that part